# Linked list - cant't create longer linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

heres funciton,it's for sokoban game.

```
LEVEL *load_levels(char *path) {
    FILE *levels;

    levels = fopen(path,"rw");
    if (levels == NULL) 
        printf("No such file\n");

    fseek(levels,0,SEEK_END);
    long lSize = ftell(levels);
    rewind(levels);

    char *maps = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*lSize);
    fread(maps, 1, lSize, levels);

    char* buffer = (char*)malloc(1025); 

    LEVEL *level = NULL,*root,*prev;
    root = NULL,prev = NULL;

    while (1) {            
      level = (LEVEL*)malloc(sizeof(LEVEL));
      while (*maps != '\n') {
            addChar(buffer,*maps);
            maps++;
            if (*maps == '\0')
                break;
        }

        level = parse_level(buffer);
        level->next = NULL;           
        if (root == NULL)
            root = level;
        else 
            prev->next = level;

        prev = level;
        strcpy(buffer,"");
        if (*maps == '\0')
           break;

        maps++;
   }

   level = root;
   return level;  
}
```

The point is, from FILE that looks like this: http://textuploader.com/9slp , this function can't procces all maps that are in this FILE, it crashes wit:

```
malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr)(((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof(struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) -1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted
```

However, if I delete at least half of file, e error(s) occur.  Any Ideas?

Level is a struct that containts:

```
char *name, 
char *description, 
char* password, 
char* map, 
level* next
```

...and parse_level parse (for example):

chicago;addie;story begins here;

```
-----#####-----------|-----#@$.#-----------|-----#####-----------
```

To `name`, `password`, `destination` and `map`.

Comment: You're allocating space for `level`, but then you overwrite `level` with the output of `parse_level`.

Comment: I thought "rw" mode wasn't supported in C. Isn't in r+? That's not the issue but I'm just curious.

Comment: But why it work for some maps, not for every?

Comment: Why some and not every?  Luck!  You haven't provided `parse_level`, but it's returning some pointer to memory (perhaps something from `buffer`?).  When programming C you can overwrite random bits of memory for a while, but it's just a matter of time before it all falls apart.  Best to fix the errors & do it right.

Comment: Is there any chance that a line in the input file is longer than the buffer size you are using? You could easily avoid the buffer by just using map as your buffer.

Comment: Could you tell me how to fix it please? I'm just begginer

Comment: @user3332838 yes, I can help: stop writing programs until you have sufficient debugging skills to get them working.

Comment: There is a limited amount of heap space.  the malloc() function extracts from the heap space.  When no space is left (all allocated by malloc, etc) then malloc fails.  More can be allocated at link time, but just because the limit is larger does not mean any ol' map file can be handled.